# Kerberos Forwarding in SSSD

Tags: ssh, pam, sshd, kerberos, sssd

So, I'm trying to set up forwarding with Kerberos and seem to have some problems.

On some of my servers I'm able to forward after receiving a ticket; however, some I'm not.

My system setup is a mixture of CentOS 5 and OpenSuSE 13.1. Some of these machines use sssd and some use /etc/krb5.conf. In all of the sshd_confs I've enabled the following options:

```
# Kerberos options
KerberosAuthentication yes
KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken yes #Not always supported

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
```

I think this may be a pam\sssd problem, but let me put the following diagram to try and clear everything up

```
----------------   ssh -K  ------------------
| OpenSuSE 13.1 | -------> | CentOS 5       |
| sssd          |          | /etc/krb5.conf |
-----------------\         | kdc server     |
                  ssh -K   ------------------
                    \            ^  |
                     \           |  v
                       - > ------------------
                           | CentOS 5       |
                           | /etc/krb5.conf |
                           | kdc server     |
                           ------------------
```

To understand this, if there is an arrow, then that means I can log in without entering another password. So, between the two kdc servers I can log in without a password.

From the OpenSuSE box, I have to specify the `-K` option when performing ssh; however, I am not able to get back from CentOS to OpenSuSE, even when at the console.

What I want is to be able to go from any machine to any other, using my ticket, and without having to do the `-K` option for SSH.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

```
Host some.host.net some-other-machine.net
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
```

should eliminate having to pass `-K`.

Comment: Maybe the OP will understand this immediately, but I don't. Please improve this answer by explaining it. Is this a shell command (or two commands)? Or is this something that should be added to a config file? Where? What do `some.host.net` and `some-other-machine.net` represent (I assume that they aren't literal)? What does this actually do/mean? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.